# Medium trust share webhosting site with Castle Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor, castle

I deployed by ASP.NET MVC 3 applications which uses Castle Windsor for DI. The application is hosted on GoDaddy's shared web hosting. I am receiving the following exception when trying to load the site. Doing some search on Google, I found that it's caused because GoDaddy hosting is medium trust.

Is there any ways to solve this problem?

> Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.InitializeLifetimeService()'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this in the end? I've got the same issue

Comment: asked 9 months ago.. I'm stuck at this too, some answers would be great...

Comment: Which version of Windsor is that? Does it still happen on v3.1?

Comment: I have this problem with version 3.1.0 too.